# How to save the selected value of a HTML dropdown box for use on the page?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, razor

I'm writing a view currently, and I am wondering if I can save the value that is selected from a dropdown `<select>` tag in HTML to use in displaying a table later in the code.

I have some JQuery code that saves the selected value to localStorage so that the same value remains selected on refresh. I would like to be able to access this value later in the page for use in displaying a table. Here is some example code.

```html
<select id="edit">
  <option value="1">1st</option>
  <option value="2">2nd</option>
  <option value="3">3rd</option>
</select>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#edit').change(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('todoData', this.value);
  });

  if (localStorage.getItem('todoData')) { 
    $('#edit').val(localStorage.getItem('todoData'));
  }
});
```

```csharp
@{
  foreach (var example in exampleModel)
  {
    if (example.intProperty == localStorage.todoData) //something like THIS is what I would like to do
    {
      doSomething();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: C# logic runs on the server side and does not have access to the client-side localStorage. To do what you require you would be best off sending the `localStorage.todoData` in an AJAX request to the server. Alternatively you could read the value from `localStorage` in client-side JS when the page is next loaded - however you already appear to be doing this. Is it not working for you?

Comment: Re. my last point, here's an example of the JS code you have actually working as it stands: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/o9ch3em0/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This program will be used by different people who need to see different tables depending on which value is selected in the dropdown box. They will all be seeing the same page, just different values on a table. That is why I need client side variables to populate the needed values. Do you know of a simple method to do this? It seems like it should be easy to save the value of the dropdown box but alas, no luck finding anything so far.

Comment: In that case you would need to store the value centrally on a server and AJAX is your best option.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for the help! disappointing that there doesn't seem to be a way to save the value of the <select> tag and access it locally, but oh well. Do you think there would be a way to save the value of a razor @Html.DropDownListFor(...) of ints as an int?